# Can't change return address on the stack — Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c

I'm trying to change the return address of a function to indirectly call another function.

```
void bye()
{
    printf("bye");
    exit(0);
}

void func1() 
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 3;
    register long rbp asm ("rbp");

    //Hack the Stack 
    *(((int*)(rbp))-1) = 30;
    *(((int*)(rbp))-2) = 20;
    *(((int*)(rbp))-3) = 10;
    printf("%d,%d,%d\n", a, b, c);
    //Trying to change the ret address
    *(unsigned long int *)((char *)rbp + 8) = 0x1169;
}

int main(void)
{
    func1();
    return (0);
}
```

Why does this not work?
The return address should be stored above rbp.
I'm changing the return address to the address of the function bye(), which I got from objDump.

Output:

```
10,20,30
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

My os: Linux Pop!_OS 21.10 x86_64

Comment: What makes you think the return address is eight bytes above `rbp`? Are you using the same ABI the book or other source you are using used? What makes you think the return address is the same size as `unsigned long int`? What makes you think 0x1169 is a useful address? Where did you get 0x1169 from?

Comment: Did you turn off ASLR?

Comment: I just turned off ASLR and I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you got the address 0x1169 from ...

If you change that line to:

```
*(unsigned long int *)((char *)rbp + 8) = &bye;
```

It prints bye, so changing the return address works with your code in principle.

Comment: I got the address from objdump. I tried your change and I still get the same error

Comment: The address from objdump is not the real address, just an offset, thats why its not working

Comment: Ok, but I still get a segmentation fault (core dumped)

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by skipping some instructions. Now the return address is at the first mov instruction.

```
*(long *) (rbp + 8) = (long) &bye + 5;
```

- 

```
Dump of assembler code for function bye:
   0x0000000000001189 <+0>:     endbr64 
   0x000000000000118d <+4>:     push   rbp
   0x000000000000118e <+5>:     mov    rbp,rsp
   0x0000000000001191 <+8>:     lea    rax,[rip+0xe6c]        # 0x2004
   0x0000000000001198 <+15>:    mov    rdi,rax
   0x000000000000119b <+18>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x00000000000011a0 <+23>:    call   0x1080 <printf@plt>
   0x00000000000011a5 <+28>:    mov    edi,0x0
   0x00000000000011aa <+33>:    call   0x1090 <exit@plt>
```

Comment: Why are you jumping to the fifth address after? I got the bye message printed with the following instruction: *(unsigned long int *)((char *)rbp + 8) = (long)&bye; -> note that I don't add 5.

Comment: For completeness: If I add 5 as you do, I get a segmentation fault.